# How to create a dynamic friends list

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, apache

I have completed a login and registration system in android using PHP, MySQL and SQLite using the tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/. (great btw). How would i go about creating friend requests (can be accepted or declined by the user) and storing the accepted friend requests, then displaying the friends to a user and then the user can click on the friends to take them to another activity.

Answer (score 2):

Well this is basically a sql question the php is irrelevant in a way, this could be applied to any language.

Firstly you would want to design a solid database structure such as the following. But keep in mind that you could have it a million different ways.

```
    -- TABLE USERS --
    +id
    +username
    +password
    +etc...
    -----------------

    -- TABLE FRIENDS --
    +id       (int, auto increment, primary)
    +userA_id (int)
    +userB_id (int)
    +datetime (datetime field or any other type)
    +accepted (bool)
    -------------------
```

This is a fairly simple setup here. When userA wants to be userB's friend you would insert a new record inside the friends table with accepted as being false (0). When userB accepts the new invite you would A: change accepted to true(1) and also create an opposite relationship. Since userA would be friends with userB, but userB would also be friends with userA. You could think of a way to take the opposite out but for a simple example this should get you started.

Then if you want to select all the friends that a user has you would do the following:

```
    SELECT (`userB`) FROM `friends` WHERE `userA`='$user_id' AND WHERE `accepted`='1'
```

Now you have the friends list. So userA would always be the current user, and userB would always be the user you want or are friends with.

Hope this helps,
Daniel